# How to cast a string to a char to fill an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, security

As the title states I am looking to create a char array and the user input should be stored as char. I am doing this to create buggy code which can fall prey to a buffer overflow. After I have this working I will truncate the input and not cause a buffer overflow. But I am having trouble figuring out how to store my strings as char in Java when I am directed to do such. Here's the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;





public class buggyCode {

public buggyCode() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6, input7, input8, input9, input10;
    char[] thisArray = new char [150];

    thisArray[0]=toChar(input1);
    thisArray[1]=input2;
    thisArray[3]=input3;


    System.out.println("Enter some characters. We are going to do this for a while");
    input1 = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter some characters. We are going to do this for a while");
    input2 = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter some characters. We are going to do this for a while");
    input3 = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter some characters. We are going to do this for a while");
    input4 = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter some characters. We are going to do this for a while");
    input5 = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter some characters. We are going to do this for a while");
    input6 = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter some characters. We are going to do this for a while");
    input7 = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter some characters. We are going to do this for a while");
    input8 = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter some characters. We are going to do this for a while");
    input9 = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter some characters. We are going to do this for a while");
    input10 = kb.nextLine();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you write `inputN` more than twice, with `N` replaced by a number, you know you need an array. Most times when you find yourself copy-pasting code with minimal changes, you know you need a loop.

> I am to fill the array at every 10 indices starting at 150 going down.

Here is how to do it properly:

```
char[] input = new char[150];
for (int i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter some characters. We are going to do this for a while.");
    char[] buf = kb.nextLine().toCharArray();
    // Copy the data into input
    System.arraycopy(buf, 0, input, 140-(i*10), Math.min(buf.length, 10));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, one thing I forgot to mention is that part of this assignment I am to fill the array at every 10 indices starting at 150 going down. Do you know how I can re factor the code to include that? Thank you

Comment: @StevenEck Please take a look at the edit. The input ends up being scattered throughout the `input` array, with the first input appearing between 140 and 150, the second input between 130 and 140, the third input between 120 and 130, and so on. Up to ten characters from the input would be copied; the rest will be discarded.

Comment: What if I wanted to not discard the extra characters and create a buffer overflow? Would I just delete the char [] buf line?

Comment: @StevenEck Then you may need to do more manipulations with the index: instead of using `140-(i*10)` expression for the starting position, compute it by subtracting the actual length from the targeted end position. For example, if your targeted end position is 150, and the user entered 15 characters, then you start copying at position 135. Make a variable for the last ending position, and subtract the length from it. Keep the end position for the next iteration, so that the strings would go into the array end-to-end. Watch out for index out of range exceptions!

Comment: Those are the exceptions I am hoping to get on the buggyCode then I will use what you helped me with for the fixedCode and the buggyCode. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

First of all this line of code will automatically fail upon starting the program remove this:

```
thisArray[0]=toChar(input1);
thisArray[1]=input2;
thisArray[3]=input3;
```

To have a clean code you can discard using string and just loop them using `for loop`

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter some characters. We are going to do this for a while");
    thisArray[i] = kb.nextLine().toCharArray()[0]; //store the first index of string to the thisArray array
}
```

Above you can see that nextLine() is then transformed into char array and get the first index which is then stored in ur char array